# Upload video fail cordova-plugin

Tags: cordova, video, phonegap, html-framework-7

I have a code for upload videos to php server. I'm using FileTransfer (cordova-plugin-file-transfer v1.6.3). All the options of the recording time limit and qty limit are ok. The issue is when i try to get the file, the filetransfer.upload(path/to, url, success, fail) is not working.

I get the name of the file. I get the size of the video. I get all but not the location, doing an alert of the fullPath location the result was:

> file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/VIDEONAME.mp4

I have w/r permissions on external storage.
I have permissions to camera.
The video is not getting any tmp_name on php server.

Can anybody help?

I try `Filetransfer()`.
I try `XMLhttpRequest()`. The issue here was creating the blob video. Tt returns `{}`. This found the video, found the file, but the blob is now the problem.

this is the filetransfer code:

```
var ft = new FileTransfer(),
path = mediaFile.fullPath,
name = mediaFile.name;
options = new FileUploadOptions()
options.fileKey =  "file";
options.fileName =  name;
options.mimeType = "video/mp4";
options.httpMethod = "POST";
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {Connection: "close"};
ft.upload(path,URL,
   function(result) {
     app.dialog.alert('Upload success: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
   },
   function(error) {
        app.dialog.alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + 
        error.code);
   },
options);
```

Comment: Maybe post some code?

Comment: Please edit your original post

Comment: I already update the post, im trying to get the file over xmlhttprequest and send it over file transfer, im having issues creating the blob, any idea?